# How to convert List to implicit operator type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to learn MVVM, and in my ViewModel I added implicit operator which converts Model to ViewModel and vice-versa, but now the question is how I can convert List of Model to List of ViewModel?

Below is the structure code which I tried to use for List Conversion  but it not working:

Person.cs

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

PersonViewModel.cs

```
 class PersonViewModel : Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator List<PersonViewModel>(IList<Person> person)
    {
        if (person == null)
            return null;

        return person.Select(c => new PersonViewModel(c)).ToList(); // This is not working

    }

    public static implicit operator PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        return new PersonViewModel
        {
            FirstName = person.FirstName,
            LastName = person.LastName,
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator Person(PersonViewModel personViewModel)
    {
        return new Person
        {
            FirstName = personViewModel.FirstName,
            LastName = personViewModel.LastName,
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok this might be stupid question but aren't you missing "new" key word?

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix Edited my post, but this time it is complaining that "PersonViewModel does not contains constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: and does it contain constructor that takes 1 argument? :D If not and you dont want that then you should do something like person.Select(x => new PersonViewModel(){FullName = c.FullName}).ToList();

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix and from where c.FullName comes?

Comment: @zee it is YOUR code, not ours.

Comment: @OndrejTucny person.Select(c => new PersonViewModel(c)).ToList(); is mine not person.Select(x => new PersonViewModel(){FullName = c.FullName}).ToList();, also Person don't have FullName property in case it's typo of "x".

Comment: Why not using local variable of Model inside ViewModel. Then you don't need converter at all. And `ViewModel.FullName` will return `Model.FistName + " " Model.LastName`. Then you can always return instance of Model from ViewModel readonly property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Cast

```
person.Cast<PersonViewModel>().ToList();
```

UPDATED

This will give you other errors. You can use extension methods and call the explicitly when you need them. Something like this (make sure you check for nulls, eventually)

```
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class PersonViewModel : Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    static class ConversionHelpers
    {
        public static Person ToPerson(this PersonViewModel pvm)
        {
            return new Person()
            {
                FirstName = pvm.FirstName,
                LastName = pvm.LastName
            };
        }

        public static PersonViewModel ToPersonViewModel(this Person p)
        {
            return new PersonViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> ToPersonViewModels(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
        {
            return persons.Select(p => p.ToPersonViewModel());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, my bad, Edited my post. Now it's giving error that "PersonViewModel does not contains constructor that takes 1 arguments".

Comment: Ah, ok:) Updated my answer. However, I think you'll end-up with more errors because you can't use that interface there and you can define implicit operators to and from base classes.

Comment: tnx, I tried casting but now it complaining that "User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type".

Comment: Why do you want to use the operator overloading and not just create some mapping helpers?

Comment: I already thought of using mapping helper, but what I guess is that when I have so many Models and ViewModel it will be harder to maintain, so it's better to have implicit operator with each ViewModel which will make code look much clean.

Comment: That's a different talk but I think the best solution would be to use composition instead of inheritance for your ViewModel-Model relationship and bind to VM.Model. Also, generally I think that implicit operators will make your code way harder to maintain as the code grows.

Comment: is it good idea to implement static classes/methods for every ViewModels? there will be lot of static methods when more ViewModels are added later.

Comment: They are just extension methods and having the static classes won't be a problem as each one will be nicely scoped. Managing these operations for the ViewModels should be straightforward as each ViewModel will eventually have a static class.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but your "MVVM pattern" seems little bid strange to me.
This my understanding of *MVVM pattern*

```
//Model
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//ModelWrapper which implements INotifyPropertyChanged if Model doesn't
//Here you can add additional properties which will serve a View's needs
class PersonModelWrapper
{
    private Person _Model;

    //Through this constructor you will create instance of modelwrapper
    //without any conversions
    public PersonModelWrapper (Person model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }

    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _Model.FirstName; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _Model.FirstName = value; 
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _Model.LastName; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _Model.LastName = value; 
        }
    }
    public string FullName
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _Model.FirstName + " " _Model.LastName; 
        }
    }

    //Through this property you will always access current model property
    //without conversions
    public Person Model { get { return _Model; }}
}

//ViewModel which used as DataContext in the View
class PersonViewModel
{
    private PersonModelWrapper _Wrapper;
    public string Wrapper
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _Wrapper; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _Wrapper = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** as answer to @Mark Feldman comment
If wrapper seems needless or as code bloat, then "ModelWrapper" can be skipped and `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be implemented by Model itself.
In case if your doesn't care about notifying view about changes of model's properties, then you don't need converting Collection of models to Collection of ViewModels.
Your ViewModel will contain property of Type ObservableCollection

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    //if you don't care about tracking changes of collection(Add, Remove)
    //then use only List<Person> without any conversions
   public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel without wrapper

```
public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyCahnged
{
    private Person _Model;
    public Person Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set
        {
            if(Equals(_Model, value) == true)
               return;
            _Model = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }

        public String FullName {get {return _ModelFirstName + " " + _Model.LastName; }}

        public PersonViewModel(Person model)
        {
            _Model = model;
        }
    }
}
```

Then converting List of Models to collection of ViewModel happened in same way through constructor

Comment: From what I can gather the question isn't so much about exposing model properties to the view by way of a view model so much as it is about how to keep view model collections synchronized with their associated model collections without experiencing code bloat. I personally don't see INPC as an exclusive requirement of the view-model <-> view relationship so I tend to add it to the models as well for both properties and collections. After that it's a simple matter of the view models subscribing to their model's CollectionChanged events while still exposing properties as you've shown here.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, I created Wrapper only because OP was exposing all properties from model to viewmodel by inheritance. In case you described in the comments see my updated answer

Comment: @MarkFeldman, as I understand this question have nothing about synchronized model's collection with viewmodel's collection, because converting one type in the another(as OP's approach) will always create new instance.